# Why do you need a separate encoder for streaming live video?

Tags: encoding, video-streaming, video-capture, rtmp, live-streaming

I have been searching for an API service that allows for browser based video capturing and encoding for the purpose of live streaming. The company I work for needs an "all inclusive" API but it does not seem to exist. The closest we have come to are streaming services that allow for a player to be embedded and the stream output to be linked to that player. These services always seem to require that you use a separate software to encode your live video.

Are there copyrights held by YouTube and Vimeo that prevent others from creating these technologies? Are there limitations with cost and scale?

Answer (score 0):

Live streaming is typically broken down into to categories:

Video conferencing where where is a limited number of participants. Here video quality typically doesn't matter. This is what browser based broadcasting solutions are designed for.

Second is large audience; where there is a single broadcaster with many viewers. Here separate encoding software is preferred because they are much more feature rich, allow for more options and controls, and allow for using good quality cameras.

COVID-19 made popular new categories of a broadcasted conference calls and simple  "one too many" broadcasts from a laptops.

Not many companies have built an end to end services for this use case as significant demand for them has only existed for a few months, and it takes years to build something like this. When Covid is over this market may dry up again.

Answer (score 0):

Qs: API service that allows for browser based video capturing and encoding for the purpose of live streaming:

[WebRTC](https://webrtc.org)

Qs: Streaming player to be embedded and the stream output:

HLS/DASH Player on Any Standard Browser

You can have a Media Gateway to convert from Webrtc to HLS/DASH (one to many or broadcasting scenario):

[Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/)

Here is a diagram to illustrate the same

[image]